# Passing a true user's UPN from the source Entra ID to the B2C federated app via JWT claim

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a customer-facing app that we need to migrate to AAD B2C for CIAM. At the same time we want our employees to be able to sign into this app with their corporate Entra ID identities. For a number of reasons we are forced to go the custom polices route and I only have couple of days to get it up and running.

While I got the basic flows up and running I'm struggling to figure out how to pass the the userPrincipalName from the source Entra ID tenant to the JWT token returned by the B2C to the client app. I tried different things but only got as far as passing the B2C UPN (the one in the cpim_...@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com format) which is not the one we need.

I don't need for the source UPN to be stored in the B2C tenant. It would be enough if its dynamically passed during the auth process.

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) article from MSFT to set up the federation between our Entra ID and the AAD B2C tenants. No problems there.

I then added the addition claim for the 'upn' in the source Entra ID tenant via 'App registrations' > 'Token configuration'. The claim is configured for token type 'ID'.

I then took the 'SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa' starter pack and the below to the config of the Technical Profile for my Entra ID integration and the RP file.

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn"/>
```

Some articles suggest to use PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" but this doesn't help either.